# Celery and Flask - RuntimeError('Working outside of application context)

Tags: python, flask, celery

In my flask application, I have `app/celery_utils.py`:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__, 
                broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', 
                include=['backend.services.spotify_service'])

def make_celery(app):

    celery.config_from_object(app.config)
    
    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

---

and then `app/__init__.py`:

```
import os
import click
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

from backend.app.celery_utils import make_celery
from backend.models import db 

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Initialize CORS, Database, and JWT Manager
    CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}}, supports_credentials=True)
    db.init_app(app)
    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    # Initialize Celery
    make_celery(app)
    
    return app
```

---

and also a `main.py` script:

```
from backend.app import create_app  

from backend.routes.auth_routes import auth_blueprint  
from backend.routes.spotify_routes import spotify_blueprint 
from backend.routes.debug_routes import debug_blueprint 

app = create_app()


# Blueprints
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(spotify_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(debug_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

---

Finally, I have my celery tasks defined in `services/spotify_service.py`:

```
from backend.app.celery_utils import celery

@celery.task
def store_user_playlists(user_id, playlists):
    with current_app.app_context():
        for item in playlists['items']:
            playlist = item
            existing_playlist = Playlist.query.filter_by(spotify_playlist_id=playlist['id']).first()
            if not existing_playlist:
                image_url = playlist['images'][0]['url'] if playlist['images'] else None
                new_playlist = Playlist(
                    spotify_playlist_id=playlist['id'],
                    user_id=user_id,
                    name=playlist['name'],
                    description=playlist.get('description', ''),
                    total_tracks=playlist['tracks']['total'],
                    image_url=image_url,
                    is_public=playlist['public'],
                    tracks_href=playlist['tracks']['href']  # Storing the href link
                )
                db.session.add(new_playlist)
        db.session.commit()
```

But when I run `celery -A backend.app.celery_utils worker --loglevel=info`, I'm getting:

```
[2023-11-23 22:39:07,228: INFO/MainProcess] Task backend.services.spotify_service.store_playlist_tracks[6b3724a1-b8d2-463f-8947-26366ba6241f] received
[2023-11-23 22:39:07,228: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task backend.services.spotify_service.store_user_playlists[e55a1193-015f-4635-80a1-a2474781e75f] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('Working outside of application context.\n\nThis typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed\nthe current application. To solve this, set up an application context\nwith app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.')
```

---

how do I run my tasks inside the app context?

Comment: Could it be that `current_app` is a different instance from your currently running app, and that causes the error? It is worth checking that.